# how to access cursor position (ie; x and y axis of page) from google map event

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I want to access x and y axis of cursor (page) in my google map event.
var mouse;

code:

```
var mouse;

function addEvent(message) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(region1, 'mouseover', function (event) {
        var x = mouse.x + 20 + 'px';
        var y = mouse.y + 20 + 'px';
        var div = $('<div id="div1">').css({
            "position": "absolute",
            "left": x,
            "top": y
        });
        div.append(message);
        $(document.body).append(div);
    });
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    var _x = e.clientX || e.pageX;
    var _y = e.clientY || e.pageY;
    mouse = { x: _x, y: _y };
}, false)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to get X and Y coordinates in relation to the top-left corner of the page:

Uses the [`mousemove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousemove) event

```
window.onload = init;
function init() {
    if (window.Event) {
    document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);
    }
    document.onmousemove = getCursorXY;
}

function getCursorXY(e) {
    document.getElementById('cursorX').value = (window.Event) ? e.pageX : event.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft);
    document.getElementById('cursorY').value = (window.Event) ? e.pageY : event.clientY + (document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop);
}
```

Then just set two elements `cursorX` and `cursorY` to display your coordinates.